# compare two generic list containing class objects

Tags: .net, list, generics, compare

How do i compare two generic list(of cSystem) in my cSystemCatalog class? I wanna know if one of the list contains more or fewer class objects, I also want to compare _systemKey and _systemName

```
Public Class cSystemCatalog
    Private _systems As List(Of cSystem)

Public Class cSystem
    Private _systemKey As Int32
    Private _systemName As String
```

Answer (score 1):

```
If _systems1.Count > _systems2.Count Then
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but how should I do if I also want to compare systemKey and systemName?

Answer (score 1):

```
If _systems1.Count = _systems2.Count AndAlso _
_systems1.All(Function(s1) _systems2.Any(Function(s2) _
s2._systemKey = s1._systemKey AndAlso s2._systemName = s1._systemName)) Then
```

Provided you can use LINQ:

```
Imports System.LINQ
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by implementing the IEquatable interface.

```
Public Class cSystem Implements IEquatable(Of cSystem)
     Private _systemKey As Int32
     Private _systemName As String

Public Overloads Function Equals(ByVal other As cSystem) As Boolean Implements IEquatable(Of cSystem).Equals
    If other Is Nothing Then Return False
    If _systemKey = other.SystemKey AndAlso _systemName = other.SystemName Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function

Public Overrides Function Equals(ByVal obj As Object) As Boolean
    If obj Is Nothing Then Return MyBase.Equals(obj)

    If Not TypeOf obj Is cSystemThen
        Throw New InvalidCastException("The 'obj' argument is not a cSystemobject.")
    Else
        Return Equals(DirectCast(obj, cSystem))
    End If
End Function

Public Shared Operator =(ByVal system1 As cSystem, ByVal system2 As cSystem) As Boolean
    Return system1.Equals(system2)
End Operator

Public Shared Operator <>(ByVal system1 As cSystem, ByVal system2 As cSystem) As Boolean
    Return Not system1.Equals(system2)
End Operator
```

Then i use the contains method on the list to compare the generic lists containing cSystem class objects:

```
Dim valuesHasBeenChanged As Boolean
If objSystemCatalog.Systems.Count = objOldSystemCatalog.Systems.Count Then
    For Each system As cSystem In objSystemCatalog.Systems
        If objOldSystemCatalog.Systems.Contains(system) = False Then
            valuesHasBeenChanged = True
        End If
    Next
ElseIf objSystemCatalog.Systems.Count > objOldSystemCatalog.Systems.Count Then
    valuesHasBeenChanged = True
ElseIf objSystemCatalog.Systems.Count < objOldSystemCatalog.Systems.Count Then
    valuesHasBeenChanged = True
End If
```